# Install Jenkins with Helm charts

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a test cluster consisting of one master and two workers and I would like to install Jenkins using Helm charts. I am following the procedure described [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/kubernetes/).

The jenkins-values.yaml looks like this(most of the values are left by default set):

```
clusterZone: "cluster.local"

renderHelmLabels: true

controller:
  componentName: "jenkins-controller"
  image: "jenkins/jenkins"
  tag: "2.296"
  imagePullPolicy: "Always"
  lifecycle:
  #  postStart:
  #    exec:
  #      command:
  #      - "uname"
  #      - "-a"
  disableRememberMe: false
  numExecutors: 0
  # configures the executor mode of the Jenkins node. Possible values are: NORMAL or EXCLUSIVE
  executorMode: "NORMAL"
  # This is ignored if enableRawHtmlMarkupFormatter is true
  markupFormatter: plainText
  customJenkinsLabels: []
  # The default configuration uses this secret to configure an admin user
  # If you don't need that user or use a different security realm then you can disable it
  adminSecret: true

  hostNetworking: false
  adminUser: "admin"
  admin:
    existingSecret: ""
    userKey: jenkins-admin-user
    passwordKey: jenkins-admin-password
  jenkinsHome: "/var/jenkins_home"
  jenkinsRef: "/usr/share/jenkins/ref"
  jenkinsWar: "/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war"
  usePodSecurityContext: true
  runAsUser: 1000
  fsGroup: 1000
  servicePort: 8080
  targetPort: 8080
  serviceType: LoadBalancer
  healthProbes: true
  probes:
    startupProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: '{{ default "" .Values.controller.jenkinsUriPrefix }}/login'
        port: http
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 5
      failureThreshold: 12
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 5
      httpGet:
        path: '{{ default "" .Values.controller.jenkinsUriPrefix }}/login'
        port: http
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 5
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: '{{ default "" .Values.controller.jenkinsUriPrefix }}/login'
        port: http
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 5

  agentListenerEnabled: true
  agentListenerPort: 50000
  agentListenerHostPort:
  agentListenerNodePort:
  disabledAgentProtocols:
    - JNLP-connect
    - JNLP2-connect
  csrf:
    defaultCrumbIssuer:
      enabled: true
      proxyCompatability: true
  agentListenerServiceType: "NodePort"
  agentListenerLoadBalancerIP:
  agentListenerServiceAnnotations: {}

  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - 0.0.0.0/0
  installPlugins:
    - workflow-cps
    - pipeline-graph-analysis
    - matrix-project
    - pipeline-model-extensions
    - docker-workflow
    - workflow-multibranch
    - lockable-resources
    - pipeline-rest-api
    - pipeline-stage-view
    - workflow-cps-global-lib
    - pipeline-model-declarative-agent
    - pipeline-model-definition
    - workflow-aggregator
  installLatestPlugins: false
  additionalPlugins: []
  initializeOnce: false
  overwritePluginsFromImage: true

  enableRawHtmlMarkupFormatter: false

  # Name of default cloud configuration.
  cloudName: "kubernetes"

 
  JCasC:
    defaultConfig: true
    configScripts: {}
    securityRealm: |-
      local:
        allowsSignup: false
        enableCaptcha: false
        users:
        - id: "${chart-admin-username}"
          name: "Jenkins Admin"
          password: "${chart-admin-password}"
    authorizationStrategy: |-
      loggedInUsersCanDoAnything:
        allowAnonymousRead: false

  sidecars:
    configAutoReload:
      enabled: true
      image: kiwigrid/k8s-sidecar:0.1.275
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      reqRetryConnect: 10
      sshTcpPort: 1044
      folder: "/var/jenkins_home/casc_configs"

  ingress:
    enabled: false
    apiVersion: "extensions/v1beta1"

  secondaryingress:
    enabled: false
    apiVersion: "extensions/v1beta1"

  backendconfig:
    enabled: false
    apiVersion: "extensions/v1beta1"

  route:
    enabled: false

  prometheus:
    enabled: false

  testEnabled: true

  httpsKeyStore:
    jenkinsHttpsJksSecretName: ''
    enable: false
    httpPort: 8081
    path: "/var/jenkins_keystore"
    fileName: "keystore.jks"
    password: "password"
    # Convert keystore.jks files content to base64 ( cat keystore.jks | base64 ) and put the output here
    jenkinsKeyStoreBase64Encoded: |
        /u3+7QAAAAIAAAABAAAAAQANamVua2luc2NpLmNvbQAAAW2r/b1ZAAAFATCCBP0wDgYKKwYBBAEq
        AhEBAQUABIIE6QbCqasvoHS0pSwYqSvdydMCB9t+VNfwhFIiiuAelJfO5sSe2SebJbtwHgLcRz1Z
        gMtWgOSFdl3bWSzA7vrW2LED52h+jXLYSWvZzuDuh8hYO85m10ikF6QR+dTi4jra0whIFDvq3pxe
        TnESxEsN+DvbZM3jA3qsjQJSeISNpDjO099dqQvHpnCn18lyk7J4TWJ8sOQQb1EM2zDAfAOSqA/x
        QuPEFl74DlY+5DIk6EBvpmWhaMSvXzWZACGA0sYqa157dq7O0AqmuLG/EI5EkHETO4CrtBW+yLcy
        2dUCXOMA+j+NjM1BjrQkYE5vtSfNO6lFZcISyKo5pTFlcA7ut0Fx2nZ8GhHTn32CpeWwNcZBn1gR
        pZVt6DxVVkhTAkMLhR4rL2wGIi/1WRs23ZOLGKtyDNvDHnQyDiQEoJGy9nAthA8aNHa3cfdF10vB
        Drb19vtpFHmpvKEEhpk2EBRF4fTi644Fuhu2Ied6118AlaPvEea+n6G4vBz+8RWuVCmZjLU+7h8l
        Hy3/WdUPoIL5eW7Kz+hS+sRTFzfu9C48dMkQH3a6f3wSY+mufizNF9U298r98TnYy+PfDJK0bstG
        Ph6yPWx8DGXKQBwrhWJWXI6JwZDeC5Ny+l8p1SypTmAjpIaSW3ge+KgcL6Wtt1R5hUV1ajVwVSUi
        HF/FachKqPqyLJFZTGjNrxnmNYpt8P1d5JTvJfmfr55Su/P9n7kcyWp7zMcb2Q5nlXt4tWogOHLI
        OzEWKCacbFfVHE+PpdrcvCVZMDzFogIq5EqGTOZe2poPpBVE+1y9mf5+TXBegy5HToLWvmfmJNTO
        NCDuBjgLs2tdw2yMPm4YEr57PnMX5gGTC3f2ZihXCIJDCRCdQ9sVBOjIQbOCzxFXkVITo0BAZhCi
        Yz61wt3Ud8e//zhXWCkCsSV+IZCxxPzhEFd+RFVjW0Nm9hsb2FgAhkXCjsGROgoleYgaZJWvQaAg
        UyBzMmKDPKTllBHyE3Gy1ehBNGPgEBChf17/9M+j8pcm1OmlM434ctWQ4qW7RU56//yq1soFY0Te
        fu2ei03a6m68fYuW6s7XEEK58QisJWRAvEbpwu/eyqfs7PsQ+zSgJHyk2rO95IxdMtEESb2GRuoi
        Bs+AHNdYFTAi+GBWw9dvEgqQ0Mpv0//6bBE/Fb4d7b7f56uUNnnE7mFnjGmGQN+MvC62pfwfvJTT
        EkT1iZ9kjM9FprTFWXT4UmO3XTvesGeE50sV9YPm71X4DCQwc4KE8vyuwj0s6oMNAUACW2ClU9QQ
        y0tRpaF1tzs4N42Q5zl0TzWxbCCjAtC3u6xf+c8MCGrr7DzNhm42LOQiHTa4MwX4x96q7235oiAU
        iQqSI/hyF5yLpWw4etyUvsx2/0/0wkuTU1FozbLoCWJEWcPS7QadMrRRISxHf0YobIeQyz34regl
        t1qSQ3dCU9D6AHLgX6kqllx4X0fnFq7LtfN7fA2itW26v+kAT2QFZ3qZhINGfofCja/pITC1uNAZ
        gsJaTMcQ600krj/ynoxnjT+n1gmeqThac6/Mi3YlVeRtaxI2InL82ZuD+w/dfY9OpPssQjy3xiQa
        jPuaMWXRxz/sS9syOoGVH7XBwKrWpQcpchozWJt40QV5DslJkclcr8aC2AGlzuJMTdEgz1eqV0+H
        bAXG9HRHN/0eJTn1/QAAAAEABVguNTA5AAADjzCCA4swggJzAhRGqVxH4HTLYPGO4rzHcCPeGDKn
        xTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBgTELMAkGA1UEBhMCY2ExEDAOBgNVBAgMB29udGFyaW8xEDAOBgNV
        BAcMB3Rvcm9udG8xFDASBgNVBAoMC2plbmtpbnN0ZXN0MRkwFwYDVQQDDBBqZW5raW5zdGVzdC5p
        bmZvMR0wGwYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFg50ZXN0QHRlc3QuaW5mbzAeFw0xOTEwMDgxNTI5NTVaFw0xOTEx
        MDcxNTI5NTVaMIGBMQswCQYDVQQGEwJjYTEQMA4GA1UECAwHb250YXJpbzEQMA4GA1UEBwwHdG9y
        b250bzEUMBIGA1UECgwLamVua2luc3Rlc3QxGTAXBgNVBAMMEGplbmtpbnN0ZXN0LmluZm8xHTAb
        BgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWDnRlc3RAdGVzdC5pbmZvMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKC
        AQEA02q352JTHGvROMBhSHvSv+vnoOTDKSTz2aLQn0tYrIRqRo+8bfmMjXuhkwZPSnCpvUGNAJ+w
        Jrt/dqMoYUjCBkjylD/qHmnXN5EwS1cMg1Djh65gi5JJLFJ7eNcoSsr/0AJ+TweIal1jJSP3t3PF
        9Uv21gm6xdm7HnNK66WpUUXLDTKaIs/jtagVY1bLOo9oEVeLN4nT2CYWztpMvdCyEDUzgEdDbmrP
        F5nKUPK5hrFqo1Dc5rUI4ZshL3Lpv398aMxv6n2adQvuL++URMEbXXBhxOrT6rCtYzbcR5fkwS9i
        d3Br45CoWOQro02JAepoU0MQKY5+xQ4Bq9Q7tB9BAwIDAQABMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQAe
        4xc+mSvKkrKBHg9/zpkWgZUiOp4ENJCi8H4tea/PCM439v6y/kfjT/okOokFvX8N5aa1OSz2Vsrl
        m8kjIc6hiA7bKzT6lb0EyjUShFFZ5jmGVP4S7/hviDvgB5yEQxOPpumkdRP513YnEGj/o9Pazi5h
        /MwpRxxazoda9r45kqQpyG+XoM4pB+Fd3JzMc4FUGxfVPxJU4jLawnJJiZ3vqiSyaB0YyUL+Er1Q
        6NnqtR4gEBF0ZVlQmkycFvD4EC2boP943dLqNUvop+4R3SM1QMM6P5u8iTXtHd/VN4MwMyy1wtog
        hYAzODo1Jt59pcqqKJEas0C/lFJEB3frw4ImNx5fNlJYOpx+ijfQs9m39CevDq0=

agent:
  enabled: true
  kubernetesConnectTimeout: 5
  kubernetesReadTimeout: 15
  maxRequestsPerHostStr: "32"
  image: "jenkins/inbound-agent"
  tag: "4.6-1"
  workingDir: "/home/jenkins"
  customJenkinsLabels: []
  componentName: "jenkins-agent"
  websocket: false
  privileged: false
  alwaysPullImage: false
  podRetention: "Never"

  command:
  args: "${computer.jnlpmac} ${computer.name}"
  sideContainerName: "jnlp"
  TTYEnabled: false
  containerCap: 10
  podName: "default"
  idleMinutes: 0
  yamlTemplate: ""
  yamlMergeStrategy: "override"
  connectTimeout: 100

persistence:
  enabled: false
  storageClass: jenkins-pv
  annotations: {}
  accessMode: "ReadWriteOnce"
  size: "8Gi"

networkPolicy:
  enabled: false
  apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  internalAgents:
    allowed: true

rbac:
  create: true
  readSecrets: false

serviceAccount:
  create: false
  name: jenkins

serviceAccountAgent:
  create: false

backup:
  enabled: false
  componentName: "backup"
  schedule: "0 2 * * *"
  activeDeadlineSeconds: ""
  image:
    repository: "maorfr/kube-tasks"
    tag: "0.2.0"
  extraArgs: []
  existingSecret: {}
  destination: "s3://jenkins-data/backup"
  onlyJobs: false
  usePodSecurityContext: true
  runAsUser: 1000
  fsGroup: 1000
checkDeprecation: true
```

Before installing Jenkins with these values, I create a PV in the jenkins namespace(even if I don't use it, it looks like the pods are not spawned without a PV):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: jenkins-pv
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  storageClassName: jenkins-pv
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  hostPath:
    path: /home/test_user/data/jenkins-volume/
```

After installing the pods using `helm install jenkins -n jenkins -f jenkins-values.yaml jenkinsci/jenkins`, the pods are running.

```
kubectl get pods -o wide -n jenkins
NAME        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
jenkins-0   2/2     Running   0          97m   10.244.2.2   kube-worker2   <none>           <none>
```

The services are looking like:

```
kubectl get svc -n jenkins
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
jenkins         LoadBalancer   10.97.219.11     <pending>     8080:30126/TCP    11m
jenkins-agent   NodePort       10.109.162.137   <none>        50000:32494/TCP   11m
```

**UPDATE 1**
The problem with the plugins was solved by adding all the required plugins under controller.installPlugins.

**UPDATE 2**
Now I am checking the UI access using `http://kube-worker2-IP:8080` or even `http://kube-master-IP:8080`, but it doesn't reply.
While checking the logs, I do not get anymore any errors, but I cannot access the UI.

```
kubectl logs jenkins-0 jenkins -n jenkins
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
2021-06-09 08:52:04.326+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log#initialized: Logging initialized @678ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
2021-06-09 08:52:04.529+0000 [id=1]     INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
2021-06-09 08:52:06.105+0000 [id=1]     WARNING o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath
2021-06-09 08:52:06.179+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-9.4.41.v20210516; built: 2021-05-16T23:56:28.993Z; git: 98607f93c7833e7dc59489b13f3cb0a114fb9f4c; jvm 1.8.0_292-b10
2021-06-09 08:52:06.555+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor#visitServlet: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2021-06-09 08:52:06.608+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2021-06-09 08:52:06.609+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2021-06-09 08:52:06.611+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.server.session.HouseKeeper#startScavenging: node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
2021-06-09 08:52:07.147+0000 [id=1]     INFO    hudson.WebAppMain#contextInitialized: Jenkins home directory: /var/jenkins_home found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
2021-06-09 08:52:07.319+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStart: Started w.@7072bc39{Jenkins v2.296,/,file:///var/jenkins_home/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/jenkins_home/war}
2021-06-09 08:52:07.356+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.server.AbstractConnector#doStart: Started ServerConnector@6f15d60e{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2021-06-09 08:52:07.357+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: Started @3709ms
2021-06-09 08:52:07.358+0000 [id=21]    INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Winstone Servlet Engine running: controlPort=disabled
2021-06-09 08:52:09.562+0000 [id=29]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started initialization
2021-06-09 08:52:09.838+0000 [id=28]    INFO    hudson.PluginManager#considerDetachedPlugin: Loading a detached plugin as a dependency: /var/jenkins_home/plugins/sshd.jpi
2021-06-09 08:52:10.043+0000 [id=30]    INFO    hudson.PluginManager#considerDetachedPlugin: Loading a detached plugin as a dependency: /var/jenkins_home/plugins/trilead-api.jpi
2021-06-09 08:52:10.690+0000 [id=28]    INFO    hudson.PluginManager#considerDetachedPlugin: Loading a detached plugin as a dependency: /var/jenkins_home/plugins/bouncycastle-api.jpi
2021-06-09 08:52:10.843+0000 [id=28]    INFO    hudson.PluginManager#considerDetachedPlugin: Loading a detached plugin as a dependency: /var/jenkins_home/plugins/command-launcher.jpi
2021-06-09 08:52:10.870+0000 [id=28]    INFO    hudson.PluginManager#considerDetachedPlugin: Loading a detached plugin as a dependency: /var/jenkins_home/plugins/jdk-tool.jpi
2021-06-09 08:52:12.846+0000 [id=29]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Listed all plugins
2021-06-09 08:52:19.105+0000 [id=30]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Prepared all plugins
2021-06-09 08:52:19.134+0000 [id=28]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started all plugins
2021-06-09 08:52:21.211+0000 [id=27]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Augmented all extensions
2021-06-09 08:52:21.255+0000 [id=30]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: System config loaded
2021-06-09 08:52:21.255+0000 [id=30]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: System config adapted
2021-06-09 08:52:21.257+0000 [id=27]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Loaded all jobs
2021-06-09 08:52:21.268+0000 [id=30]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Configuration for all jobs updated
2021-06-09 08:52:21.347+0000 [id=43]    INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$0: Started Download metadata
2021-06-09 08:52:21.366+0000 [id=43]    INFO    hudson.util.Retrier#start: Attempt #1 to do the action check updates server
2021-06-09 08:52:21.418+0000 [id=30]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Completed initialization
2021-06-09 08:52:21.634+0000 [id=20]    INFO    hudson.WebAppMain$3#run: Jenkins is fully up and running
2021-06-09 08:52:35.490+0000 [id=43]    INFO    h.m.DownloadService$Downloadable#load: Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tasks.Maven.MavenInstaller
2021-06-09 08:52:36.942+0000 [id=43]    INFO    h.m.DownloadService$Downloadable#load: Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tools.JDKInstaller
2021-06-09 08:52:36.942+0000 [id=43]    INFO    hudson.util.Retrier#start: Performed the action check updates server successfully at the attempt #1
2021-06-09 08:52:36.946+0000 [id=43]    INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$0: Finished Download metadata. 15,590 ms
```

Any idea what it is wrong in the configuration?

Comment: You have: `installLatestPlugins: false additionalPlugins: []`.see [Customizing Jenkins with plugins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/kubernetes/#customizing-jenkins-with-plugins). Be aware of: [Configure UI completely broken after upgrade](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64072).

Comment: @IanW: Thanks for your suggestion. I was applying the changes as in UPDATE 1, but the UI is still not possible to access. Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Nope, not using helm; was.just sharing what I know. Closely examine your logs for any start-up warning or error msgs.could be plugins related, so check the known problem plugins list. Might want add the `installPlugins:` section you initially missed then added to the Q.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like some of the Jenkins plugins out of date or not compatible with your Jenkins version. since the pods show running, you should navigate to the plugin page to check the details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I managed to solve it by adding the required plugins as described in UPDATE 1. The problem is that the UI is still not working. Any idea what is still wrong?

Comment: I've been adding more logs in UPDATE 2 section, but the logs are not showing any error. However, it's missing the part that gives the path where the token resides.

Comment: can you try telnet the 8080 port of the Jenkins? if it works, then try the login page which has a `/login` at the end of the URL